# "Save this image" button, for the "viewer" node in the compositor, is greyed out

Tags: compositing-nodes

As additional details, this started happening at some point in my own scenes, where the compositor is already active and with node trees. It started happening with v3.6 and persists in 4.0.
If I start a new general scene, where the compositor's "use nodes" is not checked yet, the button works normally, as I activate the compositor.

Before going into details with my Blender configuration, does anybody know what are possible causes for that button to be greyed out and unusable?
Thanks!

[image: Screenshot of the button in the node tab]